# Does reputation work differently on Area51?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, down-votes, up-votes

I understand that on SE sites that is a post gets up-voted you get reputation and if it gets down-voted you lose reputation.

On my Area51 SE account I have 41 reputation. I started out with one reputation and then got 50 for giving the site my e-mail which is a feature I guess.  I then lost a bunch of reputation from down-votes because I thought example questions were the discussion questions at the top of the proposal page.

I now have 41 reputation on my Area51 account.  After realizing my mistake I asked the discussion section [Is Area51 Discussions like an SE Meta site?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/is-area51-discussions-like-an-se-meta-site)  This question has 6 up-votes and I am still at 41 reputation.

Does reputation work different for this site or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Area 51 discussion site is Area 51's "meta" site. So you inherit your reputation from the main site (Area 51) and votes there don't affect your score.

So, apart from the different names, reputation works in the same way as on a "regular" Stack Exchange site.

I agree it is a tad confusing.

Comment: Almost the same: I believe that if you delete a downvoted question, you don't get your rep back.  (You didn't used to on the rest of the network either, but it changed a few years ago.)